# Comment key bindings in xml and java

Tags: java, eclipse

I can do comments in java code

```
Single line
comment/uncomment Ctrl + /


Multiline
comment Ctrl + Shift + /
uncomment Ctrl + Shift + \
```

I would like do the same with XML, but currently I can only do following:

```
Single line
comment/uncomment Ctrl + Shift + C 

Multiline:
comment Ctrl + Shift + /
```

Why block uncomment not works in XML file? What is the reason of having different single line shortcuts in XML and JAVA?

My key settings in my default Eclipse 2018-12 installation:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Different editors implemented in different Eclipse components (Eclipse JDT and WST).

Comment: I'm using Ctrl+Shift+C, which works in Java as well as in XML by default. Java has two key bindings for the Toggle Comment_ command: Ctrl+/ and Ctrl+Shift+C. If you prefer Ctrl+/ and would like to have this also in XML by default, be the first to report this to Eclipse as a feature request.